# Bootstrap : Carousel images are not moving

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, carousel

Hey i am trying to implement carousel on page. but issue I am facing is only active image is showing on screen. images are even not moving ie the second and third image is not showing despite beign present in the folder.
I put images in same folder where my index.html file reside. 
Please help. My code snippet is below:

```
    <!-- carousel here -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to = "2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">

    <div class="item active">
      <img src="slide_1.jpg" alt="Sale 1" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <!-- caption here -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <img src="slide_2.jpg" alt="Sale 2" class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
      <!-- caption here -->
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
  </a>

  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon"></span>
   </a>

</div>
<!-- div Carousel ends here -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the following on the page?

$('.carousel').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#carousel-methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you included the following scripts in your head tag?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
  .carousel-inner > .item > img,
  .carousel-inner > .item > a > img {
      width: 70%;
      margin: auto;
  }
  </style>
```